# Process suddenly stacking up memory when running in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, memory, memory-management, python-requests

So I wrote a script, it's collecting a timeseries of the last year via an API call (requests library) and then calculating the average. It's an infinite loop ( `while True:` ) with a sleep time of a couple of minutes and is requesting the new data, cutting off that which is older than 1 year and concatenating the new one. Then the average gets recalculated. The current timeseries (of a whole year) and the average are stored in a class object that was created before the loop begins. So it's basically:

```
Obj=Obj_Class()

while True:
    updateAverage()
    postAverage()
    time.sleep(60)
```

This all runs fine and the memory required is relatively constant at around 60-80MB.

Now, for deployment, it has been put in a Docker container and ran on the server. Therefore, the API calls were edited to grab the data directly from the Influx database that's hosted on the same server. Also "postAverage()" now does not only print the data on the monitor but puts it into the Influx database.

This is all that was changed. But suddenly, the memory (RAM) continuously grows (I ended the process after it reached 1 GB). I do not have a clue why this could be happening. Does someone have an idea what the reason could be? Where I could look or what I could look into? I know it is most likely impossible to tell without going through my code, but I figured someone here might have experienced something similar before and could offer some advice.